# In Java is it possible to create N number of arrays with different names (Not size) using loop

Tags: java

Like I need to n number of arrays with a different name .
For example n =3 and  size=4 so I  need to create 3 arrays with size 4.

Comment: Use an array of arrays.

Comment: There is no such a thing as "array name". What you probably mean is variable name.
The question indicates that some basics of the java programming language are not clear. I would advise that you revisit/restudy the following topics. (1) Java variables, (2) Java arrays. Best of luck

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to create a 2 dimensional array.
You can write a function like this to create any sized 2D array
To create 3x4 array like you wanted, invoke this:

```
int[][] myArray = create2DArray(3,4);

static int[][] create2DArray(int numberOfArrays, int size)
{
    int[][] ret = new int[numberOfArrays][];
    for (int i=0; i < numberOfArrays; i++) {
        ret[i] = new int[size];
    }
    return ret;
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way you can create n=3 arrays of int, each of size=4:

```
int[][] arrays = new int[3][4];
```

If you want to, you can now take the arrays created here and assign them to new variables like this, so that you can refer to each array by a new name:

```
int[] alice = arrays[0];
int[] bernard = arrays[1];
int[] carol = arrays[2];
```